# Separating same numbers from the list and making the list of such lists

Tags: python, list

I have the following list

```
List=['1','1','1','2','2','2','2','2','2','3','3','3','3']
```

I want to make the list of lists which takes all the same numbers.

e.g

```
List=[['1','1','1'],['2','2','2','2','2','2'],['3','3','3','3']]
```

Is there any easy way to do it ? One way I thought was to run a loop within this list and if the list element is equal to previous one then append to the same list else not. 
But if there is any other method I will be really happy to implement it.

Comment: @Bhargav Rao: Thanks I found the answer. Yes, it works fine for me.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Cheers